# Contact form with Angular and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, forms, service

I have an application using angular in frontend and rails in backend, so I'm trying to build a contact form with both, but the service returns the error:

> wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

What am I doing wrong? Check out my codes!

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  respond_to :json

  def index
    render 'layouts/application'
  end
end
```

contact_controller.rb

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController

  def send
    puts params[:contact]
  end

end
```

routes.rb

```
post 'contact_send' => 'contact#send', as: :contact_send
```

My angular service

```
$http.post('/contact_send', { name: 'Loprem', email: 'lorem@gmail.com', message: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.' }
```

Comment: Do you see your parameters in console?

Comment: Yes! Parameters: {"contact"=>{"name"=>"Ibn Claudius", "email"=>"ibnclaudius@gmail.com", "message"=>"dgdsgsg"}}

Comment: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms) ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)):
  app/controllers/contact_controller.rb:3:in `send'

Comment: Could you try something, put this line as last line of send action:
`return render json: {status: 'OK'}`

Comment: got the same error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there already is a [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-send) method defined on Ruby `Object`. This means that in your controller you're overriding a base class method but with incorrect signature.

To resolve this change the method name in your controller to i.e:

```
def send_contact
 puts params[:contact]
end
```

and update route configuration accordingly.

Comment: Now i get a "Template is missing" error, but this method won't have a view, will work as a service for my angular! How can I solve this?

Comment: @ClaudiusIbn You can do `render json: {}` or just `head :no_content`. If that doesn't work please ask another question.